What's the point of Dream Chaser?
Dream Chaser, a reusable spaceplane launching atop an expendable booster at first, to me at least, seems stupid. There's all the additional development costs, payload penalties, and maintenance hurdles, but in return what do you get? The same functions as Dragon. Overall this looks like a way to drive up launch costs. And the Shooting Star expendable module doesn't seem to improve things.
It does not however seem stupid to NASA. What am I missing?

While Dream Chaser is currently designed for cargo, I think it there is likely to be a human-rated version at some point so I'll answer based on the belief that it will one day become a human-rated spacecraft.
First off it helps to understand that NASA pays around $80,000 per kg to resupply the ISS, which is a lot more than the cost of the one way trip to low-earth orbit (~7500 per kg). What this means is that there's already a significant amount of extra cost and complexity associated with making a human-rated round-trip mission to the ISS.
Dream Chaser's different approach potentially can save some of that extra cost to outcompete SpaceX and Boeing.
Dream Chaser's heatshield is non-ablative and is thus reusable. If they get it right, then this could save them money over time. However, as we've learned from the Space Shuttle and more recently Starship, it's not easy to get this right.
Dream Chaser can land on its own on a runway. This is useful because it is expensive to have to send a ship and crew out to fetch the capsule after it lands in the ocean - especially if that ship and crew are just twiddling their thumbs or doing practice drills for most of the year.
Dream Chaser's return journey may be gentler than that of SpaceX's Crew Dragon or Boeing's Starliner. This could be important if there is a need to return sensitive experiments that could be easily damaged by jarring accelerations, such as what occurs when chutes open.
Potentially, in an emergency, Dream Chaser could get an astronaut down from the space station and to a hospital quicker, because it can fly to and land on a runway.
With its ability to return to the launch site, and its non-ablative heat shield, it is likely to be more rapidly reusable. So, if demand for access to space increases, due to space-tourism for example, Dream Chaser could make more round-trips per year than a spacecraft with an ablative heatshield. Of course, this really depends on how well its heat shield holds up during reentry relative to its competition. But, that's the theory.

I assume you know this, but someone who comes to this answer from Google might not: Dream Chaser was a competitor in the early 4 stages of the Commercial Crew program, in fact, even before Dragon entered in stage 2. So, crewed Dream Chaser was always in the cards.

...and it probably still is!

I hope so. Really want to see this...get off the ground....

@blobbymcblobby Right now the biggest threat to Dream Chaser is that it won't see much use before the ISS gets deorbited. Perhaps Hubble could use another manned servicing mission? :)

For a medivac mission I think Dream Chasers biggest advantage would be the lower g-loads during reentry.

@DanIsFiddlingByFirelight I think that's a really good point. It would be a bad day if a patient's sutures popped open or a swollen appendix burst during reentry.


What's the point of Dream Chaser?

Flexibility. Cost on its own is not the only reason for doing something.
Additional, and in some cases restating the points Phil1008 and GremlinWranger have already made:
The following comes from various materials that promoted benefits of DC:
Dream Chaser is the only spacecraft NASA currently funds that is capable of maneuvering within the atmosphere.

210 day docked duration.
Flexibility.
Its launch site, landing site, vehicle configuration, mission duration and other characteristics can be adjusted to meet the needs of diverse users. Because it does not use highly toxic fuel or require specialized infrastructure, it can land on aircraft runways pretty much anywhere. This offers numerous advantages, for example by getting payloads and astronauts returning from space to their final destinations quickly and safely. To want to land at a particular point in the US? With a capsule your opportunity to do so is once a day. With a glider you might be able to do it every 90 minutes, for a couple of windows totaling maybe a third of each day. This becomes important if there's emergencies, weather, or if you lack timing flexibility on your return.
The Dream Chaser does not use any hazardous materials for operation; therefore, the Dream Chaser can land at any suitable runway (> 8,000 feet/2,400 meters long) around the world without requiring specialized equipment. Dream Chaser can land on a compatible runway that meets the minimum length and desired width requirements, opening the door to broader landing locations and opportunities. Furthermore, by eliminating the need for hazardous materials the Dream Chaser will incur lower operational costs compared to other heritage or current development programs.
Capacity.
Although only a quarter the length of the Space Shuttle, Dream Chaser has greater carrying capacity than the other spacecraft being used in NASA’s commercial resupply program. Equipped with an expendable cargo module, it can carry five-six tons into low earth orbit—enough to supply astronauts on the International Space station for half a year. Almost all of that cargo is carried under pressurized conditions. It can also bring back almost two tons of cargo, including fragile science experiments, thanks to its modest gravity loading on reentry and landing. There is space on board for up to seven astronauts in the future.
Reusability.
The original NASA design on which Dream Chaser was based stressed affordable access to space. SNC has configured the spaceplane to be usable 15 times. Reusability is essential to holding down costs on space missions, and Dream Chaser can be used more times than some of the other spacecraft NASA employs on missions to the International Space Station. The longevity in service of the vehicle is facilitated by the modest gravity loading and gentle landing associated with its design.
Habitability.
SNC initially configured Dream Chaser to compete in crewed missions to the space station rather than cargo missions, consistent with how NASA originally conceived its purpose. The unmanned cargo version of Dream Chaser is similar to the crewed version, meaning it is readily modified to carry astronauts. Environmental controls, life support systems and seating can support a crewed version, while horizontal landing capability minimizes shock to astronauts returning to Earth after lengthy stays in orbit. You could, if you wanted to, stand on the Space Shuttle's flight deck all the way down, something you could never do in a capsule, illustrating how much gentler glider-profiles are, important if you are bringing sensitive things back from space.
Note that it (potentially) follows a similar path to Dragon's development - cargo rated first, human-rated (which takes much longer) thereafter.
Versatility.
Not only can it carry cargo and/or crew, but it can accomplish an array of missions ranging from microgravity experiments to remote sensing to servicing of deployed satellites. It potentially can be used for both civil and military missions (think crewed X-37), and with the addition of radiation hardening can be utilized in higher orbits. It also can be lofted into orbit on a variety of launch vehicles, including human-rated rockets if a decision is made to use it for astronaut transportation.

Ascent Abort.
In an ascent abort, the Dream Chaser has continuous runway landing capability from the launch pad through the Atlas/Centaur launch vehicle
trajectory. The components enabling the Dream Chaser autoland capability are typical of conventional aircraft and do not require any additional navigational aid (Navaid) equipment at the landing site. Dream Chaser is designed to use non-toxic propellants which eliminate the need for specialized propellant off-loading systems at the landing site and in post-landing processing and hangar storage facilities.

links:
https://www.forbes.com/sites/lorenthompson/2020/01/14/five-features-that-make-sierra-nevadas-dream-chaser-spaceplane-unique/
https://hsvchamber.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/advantage.pdf
https://spacenews.com/41736why-i-like-dream-chaser/
https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2012/08/dream-chaser-space-shuttles-legacy-advantage/
https://www.icao.int/Meetings/SPACE2015/Presentations/5%20-%20C.%20Lee%20-%20Sierra%20Nevada%20Corp.pdf
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_crewed_space_vehicles
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_space_station_cargo_vehicles

I remain skeptical about Dream Chaser being used for human missions, because despite advantages for landing there are disadvantages compared to a capsule in the entry phase, and especially during the ascent phase. NASA or any agency will be comparing the safety of Dream Chaser during ascent to a capsule which is a pretty high bar. A spaceplane has to maintain a higher level of functionality and control during most abort phases than a capsule, especially when over water. It’s difficult to predict whether any agency will accept a higher risk than already exists with capsules.

@StevePemberton I think the flexibility of landing location would probably trump most other issues. That is a really big advantage for human rated spaceflight. Once you de-orbit a capsule you're pretty much locked in for where you're gonna land.

@Crazymoomin - That would make it a good lifeboat for a space station. There would be possible additional risk during entry, although maybe not enough to offset the benefits of a controlled, soft landing. But I think ascent will remain a big difference in terms of safety compared to a capsule when looking at all of the possible contingency situations, something that will likely get scrutinized pretty closely, and which may relegate Dream Chaser to only lifeboat use, at least initially.

@StevePemberton I don't think dream chaser has that many disadvantages over a capsule during entry. It has a launch escape system just like a capsule, with the added benefit of being able to glide to a runway rather than having to continue on a ballistic trajectory into the ground (or more likely the ocean). Sure the heat shield is exposed, but unlike the Shuttle there's no foam covered fuel tank to fling debris at it. Starship has exactly the same issue in that regard. Finally, capsules take a lot of abuse on re-entry which limits their reusability, a gentler descent will help with that.

@Crazymoomin – during entry a spaceplane has to maintain full attitude control. Although I’m not sure any capsules can just plop into the atmosphere any which way and automatically orient themselves. But if it can then the worst case would be ballistic entry at high g and no control of the landing site after deorbit burn. As for TPS, no foam strikes but I think more things can go wrong than ablative. Again NASA is going to look at whether it is less safe, and if so how much less safe. My guess is it might be acceptable for entry, but that's uncertain right now. With ascent even less certain.

@StevePemberton fundamentally, it doesn't matter if the vehicle survives if the crew doesn't. Capsules aren't infallible in that regard either, parachutes could fail, it could begin to tumble out of control, and if the g forces are high enough the crew are dead anyway.

@Crazymoomin - I already acknowledged that capsules are not 100% safe in my first comment. That doesn’t change the fact that NASA will be comparing the safety of Dream Chaser with existing rides. If it's less safe in certain phases of the mission but safer in others, they will have to make a determination whether overall it is safe for NASA crew. If you feel confident that NASA will find Dream Chaser to be as safe or safer than a capsule, or that it they would accept less safety up to a point, you are entitled to that opinion. My opinion is that's it's far from certain what NASA will decide.

@StevePemberton mine is that capsules, reusable or not, have too many inherent disadvantages to remain as the vehicle of choice for passenger spaceflight forevermore. Maybe it will be something like Dream Chaser, maybe it will be something else in the future, but it will be different to what we have now.

@Crazymoomin - I think we all hope so, on that we can agree. But they have to make it safe and that is extremely difficult and may take a long time, longer than many people think. Like maybe a decade or more. I hope I am wrong, but I think that is more likely the case.

Key item missing is that how a rocket gets up high, gets into orbit, and comes down are all pretty much independent, and for various missions re-usable and non re-usable stages offer differing advantages.
If your mission is to have an ICBM then re-usable re-entry vehicle does not make much sense.
If your mission is a 'Save Earth' asteroid re-direct mission, using a lower performance re-usable first stage also would be questionable.
Even if your mission is 'cheap access to LEO' full re-usability may not make sense - your passengers may prefer if parts of the toilet get replaced every flight. There are also other bits of hardware that may be cheaper and easier to build and dispose of rather than re-use leading to single use trunks showing up on many current designs.
There is still the question of 'why Dreamchaser'. And for that, first answer is NASA has rejected the concept several times, schedule risk per question being one of the reasons.
Dreamchaser does offer several interesting options for a space agency however, hence the various interested parties over the years, Phil1008 outlines many of them in their answer here. The re-entry capability is certainly of note, since the combination of lifting body cross range and runway landing allow an emergency return(ie, injured astronaut) with much more options and improved outcomes over plonking into a random patch of ocean or dessert and hoping ground teams can find you, especially where weather is marginal.
Separately there is the always complex intersection of choices made for engineering, and those made to get political support for space budgets that will be shaping choices.

The commercial crew and cargo programs were always intended to use multiple providers for the following reasons:

Dissimilar redundancy -- if one launcher/spacecraft is grounded for an extended period, you can still fly missions on a different one;

Dissimilar capability -- as others have pointed out, DC has a much gentler re-entry profile than either Dragon or Starliner, making it ideal for returning delicate cargo (or, heaven forbid, injured personnel);

Competition -- in theory having multiple providers competing with each other helps keep costs down and spurs innovation;


You don't want a single spaceflight provider, just like you don't want a single auto manufacturer, or a single computer manufacturer.  Note that Boeing lobbied hard to be the sole provider for commercial transport and came damned close to winning, and how screwed would NASA be today if they had?  We'd still be paying the Russians for Soyuz flights.
Just giving everything to SpaceX would be just as bad and shortsighted as giving it all to Boeing.  Just because SpaceX is awesome today doesn't mean they will remain so in the future.  After all, Boeing was awesome too once upon a time, but those days are long gone.

I didn't interpret the question as being why does NASA want another cargo provider, I think the question was why did they select a spaceplane, which the OP posits is more expensive than a capsule. I'm not saying I agree, but that's what the question seems to be. Do you know if it actually is more expensive? If it is, do you know if NASA was willing to pay more so that they would have softer/quicker science payload return capability? Maybe they said something about that in the announcement info.
